# Make a paragraph appear inside a picture on picture hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

basically all i want to do is: Have a picture and when someone hovers over it i want some text to appear in its position(in the middle to be exact). What I have  done so far is make the picture disappear on hover but i cannot get the text to be appeared..

Html:

```
<div class="container">
<img id="atp "class="atp" src="atp.jpg">
    <div class="center">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
atp{
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:27%;
height:50%;}



container{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.center{
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
opacity: 0;
```

}

So basically, what i seek to be done is `.atp:hover{opacity:0;}` and what I also want is on atp's hover the `.center{opacity:1;]` So is there a way to put the opacity of center's to 1 when I am in the `atp:hover{}` code block?

Hope everything looks fine, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. Hope it will help you. if any changes please let me know.

```css
/********* Simple or original overlay *******/
/* Main container */
.overlay-image {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
/* Original image */
.overlay-image .image {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
/* Original text overlay */
.overlay-image .text {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 100%;
}
/********* Overlay on hover *******/
/* New overlay on hover */
.overlay-image .hover {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .5s ease;
}
/* New overlay appearance on hover */
.overlay-image:hover .hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

/********* Background and text only overlay on hover *******/
.overlay-image .normal {
 transition: .5s ease;
}
.overlay-image:hover .normal {
 opacity: 0;
}
.overlay-image .hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-image">
  <a href="LINK_URL"> 
     <div class="normal">
        <div class="text">Image + text ORIGINAL</div>
     </div>
     <div class="hover">
        <img class="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/00ccff/fff.png" alt="Alt text hover" />
     </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not really what I am trying to do. What I want is that when you hover over the picture you put, the picture is disappeared and just some text to appear in its position .

Comment: Thank you (keep in mind that while the picture is active the text doesn't appear)

Comment: @Toxicone7 If I am right please give me feedback. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  #atp {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 27%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 50;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 30;
}

#atp:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

try this, using z-index. It worked with me :)

Comment: Sorry, this is not the problem, the picture works just fine. What i can't do is that when i hover over the picture, the picture disappears (I got this working) and some text to appear on its position( I can't do this one)

Comment: Have you tried my code?? the thing is that the text is behind the picture, so when the picture disappears the text will be visible.

Comment: I didn't really got it to work with your way.. But thank you for taking time and commenting!